# Why is this for loop not working (why is the last index not showing a value)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I have this code setup to display food entries by expiration dates on a table, from top to bottom, earliest to latest. If they are within three days of the current date, the text will be yellow,if it is anytime after that, the text will be red.

Anyway, I recently was testing and realized that if two entries have the same date, the way I have my code setup, it would pull show only one of the entries however number of times that expiration date is on the table (the very first entry with that date added to be exact).

So I setup a for loop uses some queries to check if there were more than one entries and then displayed each one subsequently. Problem is, I get to the final index for the loop, and the Name associated with that date will not show up. Heres the Code:

```
<?php


      $sql1=mysql_query("SELECT email from loggedin WHERE session_id='$userid'");
      $sess=mysql_fetch_array($sql1);
      $newValue=$sess['email'];
      $sqlLength = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM food WHERE OwnerEmail='$newValue'"); 
      ?>


      <div class="table-responsive">
      <h2 class="sub-header">Expiration Dates</h2>

        <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Food Name</th>
              <th>Brand Name</th>
              <th>Food Group</th>
              <th>Location</th>
              <th>Expiration Date</th>
            </tr>

          </thead>
          <tbody>
 <?php
    $i = 0;    
 while($test = mysql_fetch_array($sqlLength)){
    $dates[$i] = $test['ExpirationDate'];
    $i++;
 }
 $length=count($dates);

 for($x=0;$x<$length;$x++){
     $year[$x]=substr($dates[$x],6,4);
     $month[$x] = substr($dates[$x],3,2);
     $day[$x] = substr($dates[$x],0,2);
 }



for($x=0;$x<$length-1;$x++){
    for($y=$x+1;$y<$length;$y++){
        if($year[$x] > $year[$y]){
            $temp=$year[$x];
            $year[$x]= $year[$y];
            $year[$y]=$temp;

            $temp=$month[$x];
            $month[$x]= $month[$y];
            $month[$y]=$temp;

            $temp=$day[$x];
            $day[$x] = $day[$y];
            $day[$y] = $temp;
        }


        elseif($year[$x] == $year[$y]){
            if($month[$x] > $month[$y]){
                $temp=$month[$x];
                $month[$x]= $month[$y];
                $month[$y]=$temp;

                $temp=$day[$x];
                $day[$x] = $day[$y];
                $day[$y] = $temp;
            }

            elseif($month[$x] == $month[$y]){
                if($day[$x] > $day[$y]){
                    $temp=$day[$x];
                    $day[$x] = $day[$y];
                    $day[$y] = $temp;

                }

            }

        }

    }
}



for($x=0;$x<$length;$x++){
    $orderedDates[$x]= "$day[$x]-$month[$x]-$year[$x]"; 
}

$currentYear=date("Y");
$currentMonth=date("m");
$currentDay=date("d");


$multiple="false";
for($x=0;$x<$length;$x++){
    $class='';
 if($multiple=="false"){

    $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM food WHERE OwnerEmail='$newValue' AND ExpirationDate='$orderedDates[$x]'") or die(mysql_error());
    $rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql2);
    if(count($rows) > 7){
        $y=1;
        $multiple="true";
        $count=count($rows)/7;
    }
 }

 else{
    $rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql2);
    $y++;

    //$x++;
 }



        $year=substr($rows['ExpirationDate'],6,4);
        $month=substr($rows['ExpirationDate'],3,2);
        $day=substr($rows['ExpirationDate'],0,2);

        if($year==$currentYear){
            if($month==$currentMonth){
                if(($day - $currentDay) <= 3){
                    $class='expBad';
                }
            }
        }

        if($currentYear > $year){
            $class='expGross';
        }

        elseif($currentYear == $year){
            if($currentMonth > $month){
                $class = 'expGross';
            }
            elseif($currentMonth == $month){
                if($currentDay > $day){
                    $class='expGross';
                }
            }
        }

?> 

            <tr>
              <td><b><?php echo $rows['Name'] ?></td>
              <td><b><?php echo $rows['Brand'] ?></td>
              <td><b><?php echo $rows['Type'] ?></td>
              <td><b><?php echo $rows['Container'] ?></td>
              <td><b><?php echo "<span class=\"$class\">".$rows['ExpirationDate']."</span>" ?></td>
            </tr>

             <?php

             if($y == $count){

                 $multiple="false";

             }
    }
    /*
    $er=mysql_query("SELECT Name FROM food WHERE ExpirationDate='$orderedDates[3]'");
    $der = mysql_fetch_array($er);
    $mer=$der['Name'];
    echo $mer;
    */
?>

         </tbody>
        </table>
```

Some info to know, my food table has 7 columns.

orderedDates gives me a correctly ordered array (I know there's a better way to do that, but I was just starting php when I wrote that)

There are 4 food entries.

Here's the problem, when I get to $x = 3, for some reason it does not display any of the column values for that entry.

Here are what the entries should look like in the table.

```
what    s   Grains  Pantry  12-02-2012
why     s   Grains  Pantry  12-02-2012
who     s   Grains  Pantry  08-04-2014
where   s   Grains  Pantry  10-04-2014
```

I only get the first 3 entries and then the 4th row is empty.

the other two columns are id and OwnerEmail

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the count() function was returning back a number other than what I thought.

Which is I thought $count would equal 1 for the value that had a unique expiration date.
But instead it was 2, which caused it to run the mysql_fetch_array function one more time than I wanted,making it point at a null value;

instead I used the following code to get the number of food items with same dates:

```
$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT Name FROM food WHERE OwnerEmail='$emailname' AND ExpirationDate='$orderedDates[$x]'") or die(mysql_error());
    $count2=0;
    while($rows2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){
    $count2++;
    }
```